# Mitmproxy downgrade from https to http

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, mitmproxy

We have a Jenkins, a gtw application that accepts HTTP requests which later forwards the data to a bit bucket server. The flow is like below:
Jenkins->Gtw(HTTP)->BitBucket url (HTTP and HTTPS).

On jenkins the requests are sent via HTTPS,
We would like to know if mitmproxy can be used as middle man that can downgrade the https to http.
Or if it is a possible way to do that on the jenkins container.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with mitmproxy as a reverse proxy (see https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-modes/#reverse-proxy). If this is a production setup, I'd recommend using nginx instead, which has better performance characteristics.